# Duplicate declaration when passing variable through as object in argument

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I am changing the way some of my functions work, instead of passing two arguments I am wanting to pass one object, containing the two arguments. So I can name the arguments more easily E.g:

**Before**

```
function myFunc(arg1, arg2) { ... }
```

**After**

```
function myFunc({ arg1, arg2 } ) { ... }
```

I have made this change in my code to `myFunc`, however when calling `myFunc` from a location it is used I get an error

```
export function anotherFunction(arg1) {
  return {
    data: myFunc({ arg1, arg2: "foo" }), // syntax error on this line "arg1"
  };
}
```

> Duplicate declaration (arg1)

Why is my passing through of `arg1` from the arg of `anotherFunction` to `myFunc` considered a "duplicate declaration"? How can I make this syntax correct?

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/satuqay/edit?js,console)

Comment: @VLAZ even though your example works, it is also showing the same sort of syntax errors (underlined in red) that I am seeing. Perhaps my code does actually work but my linter won't parse it. Why does it not lint correctly on your reproduction either?

Comment: The errors are from JSBin treating this as ES5 code. None of the errors are about a duplicate declaration. They errors areare: missing `:`, missing `;`, unexpected `,`, unexpected `)`, and unexpected expression.

Answer (score 0):

Could be your target version. try:

```
myFunc({ arg1: arg1, arg2: "foo" })
```

Comment: Why would destructuring assignment work but shorthand properties not? Both are ES6 features.

Comment: Yes, my point was your IDE may not be using es6 for the target, although your workflow might.

Comment: It should have also complained about the destructuring assignment, though.

Comment: Perhaps, but it is a simple test to rule things out.  Either it solves the issue or not.  If it does, you know where to look...